# Fragment Communicator Interface called from an ExpandableListView not working

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, interface, expandablelistview

I can pull the data out of the child and toast message it. But if I try to use my Communicator Interface at all it instantly crashes. The Communicator works fine for all my other Fragments and FragmentLists. No matter where I call a basic toastMessage method from the ExpandableListView Fragment, it constantly crashes.

```
/**
* Created by petakirikiri on 3/03/16.
*/
public class ThingsInputFragmentExpandableList extends Fragment {
View v;
HashMap<String, List<String>> movies_category;
List<String> movies_list;
ExpandableListView Exp_list;
MoviesAdapter adapter;
Communicator comm;

public ThingsInputFragmentExpandableList() {

}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.movies_expandablelist_fragment, container, false);
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Exp_list = (ExpandableListView) v.findViewById(R.id.exp_list);
    movies_category = ThingsDataProvider.getInfo();
    movies_list = new ArrayList<String>(movies_category.keySet());
    adapter = new MoviesAdapter(getActivity(), movies_category, movies_list);
    Exp_list.setAdapter(adapter);
    Exp_list.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), movies_list.get(groupPosition) + " is expanded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    Exp_list.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupCollapseListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), movies_list.get(groupPosition) + " is collapsed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    Exp_list.setOnChildClickListener(new       ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            if (movies_list.get(groupPosition) == "Determiners"){
                comm.toastMessageTest();
            }
            else if (movies_list.get(groupPosition) == "Things"){


            }
            else if (movies_list.get(groupPosition) == "Adjectives"){


            }

            return false;
        }
    });
}
}

public interface Communicator {
public void toastMessageTest();
public void setIntransitiveFragment();
public void setTransitiveFragment();
public void setPronounFragment();
public void setThingFragment();
public void setLocationFragment();
public void setVerb(String data);
public void setTense(String data);
public void setSubject(String data);
public void setDeterminerSubject(String data);
public void setThingSubject(String data);
public void setAdjectiveSubject(String data);
}

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements Communicator{

@Override
public void toastMessageTest() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "This works", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

Comment: This is not related to your question but, I believe, you shoul avoid using ExpandableListView, it's outdated and does not belong to the latest design guidelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have null pointer exception every time in Fragment because you didn't initialize and set

```
Communicator comm;
```

What you need is to override onAttach  in fragment 
 Example:

```
 @Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof Communicator )
        conn = (Communicator )context;
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    if (activity instanceof Communicator )
        conn= (Communicator)activity;
}
```

Comment: You sir, are my hero. Thank you very much for your time checking this over for me, really big help mate.